# Codeigniter Insert Non english character issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello I am inserting data in MySQL table using codeigniter by following query

```
$subcat_name="Hellome� testing";
$this->db->insert("table",array("name"=>"$subcat_name");
```

I am echoing its Equivalent SQL Query is following

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES ('Hellome� testing');
```

**Question:**

Why data is not inserted in Database while SQL Query is proper?

Comment: try using `utf8_encode($subcat_name)` before you pass `$subcat_name` to the insert function

Comment: @Skalbhile Thanks for reply let me check

Comment: @Skalbhile It insert data but not properly inserted. It insert something like `Hellome testing`

Comment: Make sure that your script is saved with encoding utf_8. and your table collation is utf8_general_ci. For more details read
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8281157/4050077

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using **HTML NUMBER** of the symbol which you want to instead of using `�` . Go to following link::

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

and find the symbol you want put the **HTML NUMBER** of that, i think that will work.

Comment: I am trying to insert `Hellome� testing` string in Database but not inserted